# Block a Processes Child Window?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-services, process

I am launching a process in C# .NET that for some reason opens a message box when it is initially launched. What I need to do from my application is find some way to either prevent this message box from ever being opened, or basically "click" the OK button on the message box from my code.

The message box is causing the process to hang when we run it as a service, so I now need to find some way to either prevent that box from ever opening or just close it (select OK) from my code.

I have been looking at some Win32 API samples, but I have never had to use it before and it looks a bit strange. Any suggestions would be great!

*Edit*

Here is a batch file that was supplied as a work around for the issue. However I would much prefer to have it running an executable if possible. The explanation was that using the -supw parameter (to set a password on the server) causes this message box to popup. This batch file is tested and works, but it requires you have a duplicated executable (murmur2.exe) created which is ghetto.

```
set /p VAR= < superadmin.txt
start murmur2.exe -supw %var%
ping 0.0.0.0 -n 3 > NUL
tskill murmur2
murmur.exe
```

Comment: I assume the app that you are spawning can't be changed?

Comment: Not really. It is open source but it has a list of dependencies the length of the bible.

Comment: It's obviously not designed to be run from a service. You need to change your app from a service into a user-mode application. Services can't show a UI, and when a service attempts to show a message box, it will crash.

Comment: @Cody am I imagining? I'm sure I remember the default option being taken... Maybe that was a specific context.

Comment: @Marc: I believe that's the backwards-compatibility hack you get if you call `MessageBox` with the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag. If the app being called here isn't designed to run from a service, even under earlier versions of Windows, it's unlikely it specifies that flag. I'm not sure what happens without it, but I definitely remember seeing reports that it hangs the process.

Comment: seems it might be easier to rewrite the wrapped app a little, if its open source.

Answer (score 2):

`PostMessage(FindWindow("#32770",*Title of the message box*),WM_CLOSE,NULL,NULL);`

Since there *might*(with a very slim chance) be a same window opened with the same class name with the same title at the same time, this is not a fail proof way. However the alternatives are simply an overkill. If you really want to make it fail proof, you'll have to call `EnumWindows` to enumerate all top-level windows, then for each window, call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and compare the window's process id with your launched process' id. If they are equal, you can then call `GetClassName` and `GetWindowText` to compare the class names(always "#32770" for common dialogs) and the title of the message box to verify that you're trying to close the right window. Once it's done, you can call PostMessage with WM_CLOSE using the hWnd that you found.

Comment: you will need to wait until the window is created before posting the message

Comment: In general, this would work. But it won't work when the process attempting to generate the message box is being run as a service. The window will never get opened because services can't show a UI. And since it's never opened, it doesn't get a window handle, and you can't send it a close message.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Simple calls to FindWindow with a short interval wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Cody Gray. Oops. I guess didn't fully read the question. I agree with what you said in your comment: it can't run a Win32 GUI program as a service. However, it is clear that the user *is* seeing the message box and in one way or the other, so the program is being run as a regular process. The only possible explanation for this would be that the service itself in turn creates another process (using `CreateProcessAsUser` or something). Anywho, in any case, this method should work.

Comment: Not sure where that's clear. He says the message box appears when the application is *not* run as a service, which makes sense. But he doesn't say the message box appears when the process is run as a service, he just says it causes the process to hang. You *might* have some luck with `CreateProcessAsUser`, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: Umm. The only and/or obvious solution to a problem where a process, which you really don't know anything about except for the fact that it's running as a service, just "hangs" would be to reverse engineer the program and inject a code that get's rid of the block condition :p

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys! I have added a bit more under *Edit* part of the first post that might offer a bit more information. I suppose I could just recreate the batch file as a C# NET application, but I would prefer just to launch it once if possible.

Comment: @Cody I missed the bit that this was a service. D'oh!